# Read properties file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

There are 4 projects.

1. project1
2. project2
3. project3
4. project4

`Project2` has 2 projects in build path. i.e. `project1` and `project3`

`Project1` has a class that reads property from a properties file. `Project2`
can access that class to getProperty.

`project4` has only one `project3` in its build path.

It means `project3` is in build path of two projects.

I want to get property in `project4`. I have no choice to include `project1` in `project4`.
Whatelse can I do to get property?

Can I do one think like: While starting project2. Load a list with properties in project3. Then access that from project4?

Comment: You have to include project1 in build path of project4. No other option is there because the class that reads properties file is in project1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **project 2** can have access to classes in **project 1**, so an interface will be created in **project 3**. A **class** in project 2 will implement this interface having function to read property from properties file. **Project 4** is in shared library of **project 2**. Spring does a trick. A method in project 4 gets bean through applicationcontext, of that **class** which was created in **project 2**. After getting this bean, property can be accessed.